# Compare two arrays simultaneously and log only the even numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm trying to compare two arrays at the same time and log the only the even values. This is the code I came up with, which does log correctly,  but I'm certain this is not the correct way. How can I improve this code?

"Take arr1 and arr2 and log only the even ones"

```
const arr1 = [5,8,2,1,5,7,3,4,5,8,1,2,4,8,3,1,4,5]; 
const arr2 = [15,26,74,12,3,6,9,1,2,5]; 

for (var i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if ((arr1[i] % 2) === 0) {
        console.log(arr1[i]);
    }
}

for (var i=0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if ((arr2[i] % 2) ===0) {
        console.log (arr2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576)

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: I think this could run in a couple of languages could you specify explicitly which one you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Concat your arrays and then run the code on the single array.

```js
const arr1 = [5, 8, 2, 1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 8, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [15, 26, 74, 12, 3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 5];

const mergedArray = arr1.concat(arr2);

for (var i = 0; i < mergedArray.length; i++) {
  if ((mergedArray[i] % 2) === 0) {
    console.log(mergedArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This code's work perfectly, but the problem is, you don't have a solution to the elements that are already exist in array.

Comment: The OP never requested that each element only be printed once. The request was to print all the even numbers in two arrays more efficiently

Answer (score 0):

You could also just traverse both arrays in one loop and check for even numbers in both if you can't add more space. It would be even more efficient to run two for loops, where the first goes from `0 to min(arr1.length, arr2.length)` and the second goes from `min(arr1.length, arr2.length) to max(arr2.length,arr1.length)` (of course you'd have to check to see which is bigger in advanced). Also I believe [you should go here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for questions related to improving the efficiency of code that runs correctly.

```js
const arr1 = [5, 8, 2, 1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 8, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [15, 26, 74, 12, 3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 5];
const mx = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length);
for (var i = 0; i < mx; i++) {
  if ( i < arr1.length && (arr1[i] % 2 === 0)) {
    console.log(arr1[i]);
  }
  if ( i < arr2.length && (arr2[i] % 2 === 0)) {
    console.log(arr2[i]);
  }
}
```